# SwipeCellKit does not swipe cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I  want to implement UITableView's `UISwipeActionsConfiguration` for a `UICollectionView`. In order to do so, I am using [SwipeCellKit - github](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit)

---

My `UICollectionView` adopts to the `SwipeCollectionViewCellDelegate` protocol. And the cell inherits from `SwipeCollectionViewCell`.

#### ViewController  with UICollectionView

```
class SwipeViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.register(SwipeableCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SwipeableCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 4, right: 0)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.97, alpha: 1)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        return collectionView
    }()

    var items: [String] = {
        var items = [String]()
        for i in 1 ..< 20 {
            items.append("Item \(i)")
        }
        return items
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.setConstraints(topAnchor: view.topAnchor,
                              leadingAnchor: view.leadingAnchor,
                              bottomAnchor: view.bottomAnchor,
                              trailingAnchor: view.trailingAnchor,
                              leadingConstant: 10,
                              trailingConstant: 10)
    }
}

extension SwipeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 80)
    }
}

extension SwipeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SwipeableCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! SwipeableCollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = BackgroundColor.colors[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
}

extension SwipeViewController: SwipeCollectionViewCellDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, editActionsForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
        guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

        let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
        }


        return [deleteAction]
    }

}
```

#### SwipeCollectionViewCell

```
class SwipeableCollectionViewCell: SwipeCollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.addSubview(nameLabel)

        nameLabel.setConstraints(topAnchor: self.topAnchor,
                         leadingAnchor: self.leadingAnchor,
                         bottomAnchor: self.bottomAnchor,
                         trailingAnchor: self.trailingAnchor)

        self.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    static let identifier = "TaskListTableViewCell"


    private let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label =  UILabel()
        label.text = "Simulator user has requested new graphics quality"
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }()


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

After doing so, when I swipe the cell, the `deleteAction` overlaps with the content of the cell.

[image]

As you see in the screenshot, the cell's content overlaps with the `deleteAction` text.

#### Update

`setConstraints` sets  views's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`

Comment: I guess the issue might be in the UILabel in your cell, maybe you can try (label.clipsToBounds = true) so it doesn't go out of the container view.

Comment: @omar no, same issue even If I use an img or a 20X20 uiview either on the left or right side.

Comment: try adding your `UILabel` in the cell's `contentView` instead.

Comment: @mahan Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add nameLabel to `contentView`.
Change

```
self.addSubview(nameLabel)

nameLabel.setConstraints(topAnchor: self.topAnchor,
            leadingAnchor: self.leadingAnchor,
            bottomAnchor: self.bottomAnchor,
            trailingAnchor: self.trailingAnchor)
```

to

```
self.contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)

nameLabel.setConstraints(topAnchor: self.contentView.topAnchor,
            leadingAnchor: self.contentView.leadingAnchor,
            bottomAnchor: self.contentView.bottomAnchor,
            trailingAnchor: self.contentView.trailingAnchor)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: @mahan I think the lib will adjust contentView of cell when swipe, then I try it with your sample code. It did work